# Why does -fno-stack-protector reverse the order in which these strings are stored?

Tags: c, memory, stack

I have the following function:

```
void f(){
    char a[]="THIS IS A STR 1";
    char b[]="THIS IS A STR 2";
    char c[]="THIS IS A STR 3";
    char d[]="THIS IS A STR 4";
}
```

When I compile and run this program normally, these strings are allocated on the stack like this:

```
08 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 ................
10 71 c7 64 fc 7f 00 00 07 a9 90 7b 24 56 00 00 .q.d.......{$V..
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 31 00 THIS IS A STR 1.
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 32 00 THIS IS A STR 2.
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 33 00 THIS IS A STR 3.
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 34 00 THIS IS A STR 4.
a0 69 d9 76 c8 7f 00 00 00 dc ad e1 c7 89 e9 11 .i.v............
30 71 c7 64 fc 7f 00 00 37 a9 90 7b 24 56 00 00 0q.d....7..{$V..``
```

The stack grows towards smaller memory addresses, ("upward" in this example) so the order in which these strings are being stored seems reversed to me.

Whereas when I compile and run with -fno-stack-protector, I get the "correct" ordering.

```
00 00 00 2e 10 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 ................
80 20 05 0f ff 7f 00 00 88 58 bb 32 96 55 00 00 . .......X.2.U..
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 34 00 THIS IS A STR 4.
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 33 00 THIS IS A STR 3.
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 32 00 THIS IS A STR 2.
54 48 49 53 20 49 53 20 41 20 53 54 52 20 31 00 THIS IS A STR 1.
a0 20 05 0f ff 7f 00 00 a4 58 bb 32 96 55 00 00 . .......X.2.U..
88 21 05 0f ff 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 .!..............
```

I was under the impression that all the stack protector does is put in stack canaries, so why would it reorder how memory is allocated like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that the stack "grows" refers to the locations of different stack frames when you have nested functions or blocks. It will also grow in this direction temporaries need to be allocated on the stack dynamically.

However, the location of variables within a stack frame is completely arbitrary; there's nothing that requires it to be in the same order as the variable declarations. There are many reasons why the compiler might reorder variables within a stack frame; for instance, variables with smaller alignment requirements might be moved together, to minimize padding.

The fact that these strings are reversed when you use `-fno-stack-protector` is probably just a side effect of different code paths through the optimizer. I doubt there's any specific reason for it, but it shouldn't matter.